# Mapping one to many relationship in separate table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to develop a system for managing dormitories. Since I don't have much experience with databases, I am stuck on a problem and I have a solution but I am not sure if this would be the right approach. 
So I have Room and User. Each user can be accommodated in one room, but one room can accommodate more users. I would like to manage this relationship in one entity - Accommodation. Here I would have more properties, like start/end Date, etc.

I am using Hibernate to map the tables. From what I've read, persisting Collections from Java can be done in two ways, either by @OneToMany or by @ElementCollection. I am not quite sure if I should define this relationship in the Room entity or in the Accommodation entity? If I do it in the room entity then the Accommodation would hold just fk from the room/user tables? 
Also, is it possible to only fetch the primary key when doing one-to-many relations instead of getting the whole object? I know that FETCH.LAZY does this, but in my Accommodation entity ideally I would want to store only Set studentsIds.

Thank you in advance.

```
@Table(name = "student")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room", nullable = false)
    private Room room_number;

}
```

Here is the Room entity

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "room")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Data
public class Room
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "room_number")
    private Long roomNumber;

    @Column(name = "location_address")
    private String locationAddress;

    @Column(name = "dormitory_name")
    private String dormitoryName;

}
```

Accommodation entity

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "accommodation")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Data
public class Accommodation extends Entity {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_number")
    private Room room_number;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room_number", // I am not sure about this
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            orphanRemoval = true) private List<Student> students;

    @Column(name = "date_from")
    private Date dateFrom;

    @Column(name = "date_to")
    private Date dateTo;
}
```

Comment: If you add a date, then do you still have a one-to-many relationship? It is obvious that one user has one active room (i.e. a room he "lives" in at a given point in time), but s/he might have a history of rooms s/he has already lived in, thus making it a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @Turing85 is right.  Perhaps you want to change the semantics of your classes and simply have Room and Student entities that don't reference each other but have a StudentRoomAllocation entity which state which room a student will be in and the start and end dates for that allocation.

Comment: @Turing85 yes that is a very good point, I haven't thought of it by now. If I am not mistaken we are talking about junction table here, right? So I would have Set<Rooms> in the Student entity and Set<Student> in the Room entity? In that case, now referencing to my second question in the original post, is there a way to hold Collection of Ids (primary keys) instead of objects?

Comment: Normally, Hibernate should take care of this. You define the one-to-many relationship on the "one" side, in your case on the `Room`, through e.g. a `Set<User>` and annotate it with `@OneToMany`. On the "many"-side, in your case the `User`, you define an attribute of type `Room` and annotate it as `@ManyToOne`, specifying the `JOIN`-column. Hibernate will then use `Room`'s primary key to do the mapping in the `user` table. Normally, you do not need an additional table for joining if you have a one-to-many relationship. (cont.)

Comment: If you have additional information to the room, e.g. dates, this would be a separate Object (e.g. `DateDecoratedRoom`). You would then define a one-to-many relationship from `Room` to `DateDecoratedRoom` and a one-to-one relationship from `DateDecoratedRoom` to `User`.